# How to compute the ray class field of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, class-field-theory, sagemath, magma-cas

I want to verify Thm 5.6 in Silvermans Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves that says $K(j(E),h(E[\mathbb{c}])$ is the ray class filed of $K$ modulo $\mathbb{c}$.
I choose $K= \mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $\mathbb{c} = 2,3,4$. The $j$-invariant is in $\mathbb{Q}$ because its class number is $1$. And the Weberfunction is $h(x,y)= x^2$. 
I computed the torsion points and then we have $K(h(E[2])) = K$, $K(h(E[3])) = K(\sqrt{3})$ and $K(h(E[4])) = K(\sqrt{2})$.

Now I want to compute the ray class fields via an other method. I know something about PARI, but couldn't find there something. 
I am looking foreward for any ideas or help with some copmuter algebra (magma, sage, PARI). Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can play in [magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) with `P<x>:=PolynomialRing(Rationals()); K<i>:=NumberField(x^2+1); O:=MaximalOrder(K); c := 3*O; R:=RayClassField(c); R`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it, but I am such a beginner that i cannot interpret the result. What does this "FldAb, defined by (<[2, 0]>, [])" mean? How is this the sturcture of $K$?

Comment: Anama - You can use L := NumberField(R) to get an explicit description of field over $K$.  There is a similar question with good answers here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876353/explicit-example-of-computing-ray-class-field-for-imaginary-quadratic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [explicit example of computing ray class field for imaginary quadratic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876353/explicit-example-of-computing-ray-class-field-for-imaginary-quadratic)

Comment: @JohnM That questions asks for an explicit example, whereas this question asks for help with the computation of a particular example.  They appear to be related, but this is not (to my mind) a duplicate.  I am voting to leave this question open.